# Запуск Функции в QMainWindow после закрытия Qwidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты

В главном окне `MainWindow` есть `ComboBox`, который содержит имена берущиеся из БД. 
В этом же окне есть кнопка вызывающая `WidgetOne`. В `WidgetOne` вносится информация данных в БД по типу имени и других параметров. 
После нажимается кнопка, которая добавляет в БД новые данные и окно закрывается.

Стоит задача после закрытия `WidgetOne` автоматически вызвать метод `endWidget()`, который находится в `MainWindow`.

Прилагаю пример где и как располагаются классы, функции и т.д. в соответствии с изначальным кодом.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.button = QPushButton('click_me', self)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        self.button.setGeometry(50, 50, 50, 50)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.newWidget)
        # Главное окно, здесь еще должен быть QComboBox в котором имена "Операций"(берется из БД)

    def newWidget(self):
        self.wid = WidgetOne()
        self.wid.show()
        # Вызывает Widget, форма, куда добавляется новая операция с именем и прочими параметрами


    def endWidget(self):
        print("it's ok")
        # функция, обновляющая QComboBox с новыми именами (стирает и создает заново беря данный с базы данных SQLite)
        # в главном меню


class WidgetOne(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.button1 = QPushButton('lul', self)
        self.button1.setGeometry(50, 50, 25, 25)
        self.button1.clicked.connected(self.close)
    # Здесь идет функция добавления в Базу данных новой операции с именем и другиими параметрами
    # после добавления всего что нужно, нажимается кнопка, все записывается в базу данных и QWidget закрывается


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class WidgetOne(QWidget):
#    def __init__(self):
#        super().__init__()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                               # +
        super(WidgetOne, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.Window)   # ! Qt.Window
        self.parent = parent                                       # +

        self.initUI() 

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.button1 = QPushButton('lul', self)
        self.button1.setGeometry(50, 50, 25, 25)

#        self.button1.clicked.connected(self.close)                 # -
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.parent.endWidget)         # +


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.button = QPushButton('click_me', self)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        self.button.setGeometry(50, 50, 50, 50)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.newWidget)

    def newWidget(self):
#        self.wid = WidgetOne()
        self.wid = WidgetOne(self)                                     # + self
        self.wid.show()

    def endWidget(self):
        self.wid.hide()                                                # +
        print("it's ok")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]